# Does the general solution of a second-order-non-homogeneous-linear-differential equation with complex roots count as a cosine/sine term?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Say a second ODE $D(x) = Acos(Bx)$ has the general solution $C_1e^{\alpha ix} + C_2e^{\beta ix}$
where $\alpha i$ and $\beta i$ are the complex roots of the auxiliary equation of $D(x)$;

Then, does the particular solution have to be in the form $C_3x^ncos(Bx) +  C_4x^nsin(Bx)$ where n is an integer and > 0, since the general solution can be converted to the form containing sine and cosine functions?

EDIT: $D(x)$ is a second order linear non homogeneous differential equation with real coefficients. $\alpha i$ and $\beta i$ are complex conjugates of each other. Apparently there was some ambiguity there.

Comment: Is that second order, with real coefficients? Where then $β=-α$ because of complex conjugate roots? What do you know about eigenfrequencies and resonance?

Comment: I just started a course in Waves and Vibrations. We need to be able to solve such equations...so I know a little but probably not as much as you. And yes $D(x)$ is second order with real coefficients. $\alpha i$ and $\beta i$ are assumed to be complex conjugates of each other considering that I stated they are complex roots of the auxiliary. Sorry for the ambiguity, I'll edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general rule for $L(y)(x)=A\cos(Bx)$ is that for the particular solution one can take the trial function $y_p(x)=C\cos(Bx)+D\sin(Bx)$ if $iB$ (and thus also $-iB$) is not a root of the characteristic or auxiliary polynomial of $L$.

In the case where $iB$ is a root of multiplicity $n$, the trial function is indeed $y_p(x)=Cx^n\cos(Bx)+Dx^n\sin(Bx)$.

However, since a differential equation of order 2 can only have one complex conjugate pair of roots, in the presented situation there only can occur $n=1$ (and $n=0$).